# does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import>>

Tags: django

I'm following the django tutorial and ran into this error. took some time to look at a lot of other people who hit this same error and see a lot of cases where "urlpatterns" was not spelled correctly but that doesn't seem to be my issue.

this is my code:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import include, path



urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),    
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I also notice when I comment out the whole line of code that has path with include. the error goes away.

[stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cbLL.jpg)

Comment: in your polls app, do they have urls.py?

Comment: Can you provide stack trace of your error in question ? Also check if `polls` is registered in `settings.py` as an app (check `INSTALLED_APPS`)

Comment: ming yes i do have a urls.py in my polls app

Comment: thank you k33da_the_bug for responding. added my stack trace to the question. its weird because while following the django tutorial when i get to where I was they didnt say to add my app to settings even though I know your suppose to. but even when i did add my polls app to settings i still got the same error